# Django как использовать numpy библиотеку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, numpy

Как корректно подключить numpy библиотеку для Django проекта ?
Django (apache + mod_wsgi)

после импорта import numpy ... сервер/сайт не грузит страницу думаю здесь косяк какой то импорт неверный или что то еще надо добавить не просто import numpy. Если убрать import numpy то сервер работает грузит страницу. Может переменные окружения какие то надо добваить еще ? –

Comment: `import numpy` и всё, в чём проблема?

Comment: пробовал не работает, думаю может как то отдельльно надо в django прописывать типо как в setting.py в качестве утилиты

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? У меня работает

Comment: значит косяк на моей стороне :/

Comment: после импорта import numpy ... сервер/сайт не грузит страницу думаю здесь косяк какой то импорт неверный или что то еще надо добавить не просто import numpy. Если убрать import numpy то сервер работает грузит страницу. Может переменные окружения какие то надо добваить еще ?

Comment: Если импорт неверный — может, надо numpy просто установить?

Comment: да нет numpy установлен корретно

Comment: В правильное ли место установлен? mod_wsgi использует тот же питон, что и тот, в который вы установили? А если запускать Django напрямую без mod_wsgi?

Comment: django без mod_wsgi не работает

Comment: у django вроде как есть своя папка ***\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib где находятся его INSTALLED_APPS вот думаю туда закинуть папку с numpy и прописать в settings.py

Comment: Вас обманули, Django без mod_wsgi замечательно работает. Не надо ничего никуда закидывать, надо просто установить numpy в том же питоне, который используется в mod_wsgi. Или если совсем не получается, то отказаться от mod_wsgi и использовать что-нибудь другое

Comment: а как понять какой питон используется в mod_wsgi ? у меня питон один установлен одна версия/без виртуального окружения

Comment: Для начала покажите полный текст ошибки (вдруг мы случайно о разных вещах говорим)

Comment: а ошибка не возникает просто сервер не грузиться ( ... нет логов

Comment: Значит смотрите лог-файлы apache, в них mod_wsgi должен был написать что-нибудь информативное

Comment: логи apache смортел mod_wsgi ниче не сообщил к сожалению / буду искать обходной путь

Comment: главное прикол в чем: на сервере разработки manage.py runserver все нормально пашет с numpy, но в боевом режиме , те когда задеплоил django на сервере apache + mod_wsgi не хочет бляха муха

Comment: А чистый venv с установкой необходимых пакетов пробовали?

Answer (score 1):

Поверь установлен ли numpy.
Активируй окружение и сделай:
`pip freeze`

Если в аутпуте нет numpy доустанови его.
`pip install numpy`